# Change the Text color and Text size in Tab Widget...?

Tags: android, tabs, android-widget

I want to change the Text color and Text size in the `TabWidget`. Is it possible directly without taking `TextView` or not.

Please tell me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can completely customize how you want the text and background of a tab in a TabHost to appear. See this blog for a very good tutorial on how to do it: http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=136

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make custom tab indicator, [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.TabSpec.html#setIndicator%28android.view.View) is something you might need to look

Answer (score 0):

Here is a previous answer on a similar question with great tab customization possibilities. [Android - Remove Icon from TabHost/TabWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152180/android-remove-icon-from-tabhost-tabwidget/7152324#7152324)